# Punch Jab: Where to Place Right Hand during block

Tags: self-defense, technique, mixed-martial-arts, boxing, muay-thai

Recently I started sparring. In boxing,  the athlete who jabs is told to keep right hand tucked at right side of face (pictures below). Just curious, why the right hand isn't taught to be more in front of the face, tucked below the eyes ready to block or catch/parry the punch? Is there a reason its traditionally taught to keep at side? I seemed to have little more luck in front, as its hard to throw a long hook to left side.

Pictures below where face is more open to punches, etc

**Resources:**

https://youtu.be/OeedpzLRe2E?t=66

https://youtu.be/CmpqqsmiP70?t=226

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It protects you from hooks.
2. It is a better position from which to launch a variety of punches.
3. Keeping your fist further forward as you describe reduces the potential power of your punch.

(Catching or parrying is made more difficult from this position, but only marginally, and this is typically considered a secondary concern to the reasons provided above).

Comment: I agree, but would add that a bear handed stance will always be different from a gloved stance anyway.

Comment: whats a bear stance? @HuwEvans is it this? https://www.akban.org/wiki/Hoko_no_kamae,_Bear_stance_-_Ninjutsu

Comment: @mattsmith5. I think Huw might have meant 'bare handed', not 'Bear handed', but I could be wrong.

Comment: yes bare handed not bear handed.

Comment: 4) additionally its harder to pivot if other hand is in front of face 5) if its held in front too close, your own boxing glove bouncing back at your face is very painful, I tried both strategies

Comment: thanks, any answer for this? https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/13225/muay-thai-roundhouse-kick-using-kick-shields-vs-thai-pads-different-technique surprised no one knows solution for this either