# Muay Thai Roundhouse kick, what angle to bring out knee and leg

Tags: technique, mixed-martial-arts, muay-thai, kicking

When doing a roundhouse kick, is there a rule for what angle the knee should come out at ? My coach says to bring the knee over at straight vertical angle 0 deg, and rotate the leg over while you extend.

In this angle below, the knee is out at a 45 degree right, while he extends the leg. My coach says not to do this. Is there a general rule for kicking? Or is each variation okay? green line below for reference

Another angle question, last question ([Muay Thai Roundhouse Kick: Using Kick Shields vs Thai Pads, different technique?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/13225/muay-thai-roundhouse-kick-using-kick-shields-vs-thai-pads-different-technique)) was about final Rotation of leg. This is how about to bring it out initially.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good video resource from Damien Trainor after research: (feel free to add more answers)

https://www.instagram.com/reel/CZkRZp3AUtm/

**In Summary:**

1. Straight kicks are less noticeable and less telegraphed
2. Round kicks may have more power and allow to kick "wide to get past someone’s defense

> Both kicks start at the same time, but the key differences to notice
> are, the angle of the knee as it starts and which kick strikes first.
> ⁣⁣⁣ ⁣⁣⁣ Even though it’s called a roundhouse kick it’s important to
> remember when throwing it that you don’t want to throw it too round.
> By doing this you’re telegraphing what you’re doing, it takes too long
> to get to the target and you’re losing power.⁣⁣⁣ ⁣⁣⁣ Think of a
> circle, you want to get from one side to other as quick as possible,
> fastest way to do that that is straight through the middle. Same
> applies for the kick, your want the kick go at a relatively straight
> angle and then turn your hip over at the last second. ⁣⁣⁣ ⁣⁣⁣ Key
> points when throwing the kick are pivot the standing foot, throw the
> leg direct to the target, turn the hip and shoulder over, guard, make
> contact with your shin. ⁣⁣⁣ ⁣⁣⁣ Just remember EVERY technique has a
> textbook way of throwing it.... however, fighting can be
> unpredictable. So with that in mind, there will be times when you have
> to adapt to the situation at hand in order to land something. In other
> words at some point you may have to swing wide to get past someone’s
> defence. That adaptation comes from experience....someone left a
> comment not too long back which I thought was great “learn the rules
> well before you break them”. ⁣⁣⁣